# Pyautogui locate functions in a minimized window

Tags: python, windows, automation, screenshot, pyautogui

I am developing a code using pyautogui where i detect an event in the window "A" and them, with alt+tab, execute an action in the window "B". I would like to know if it is possible to do this, but with the window "A" minimized, so it doesnt have to alt+tab all the time (the solution doesnt necessary has to be with pyautogui).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you intended to use the locate function with pyautogui, whether or not it's LocateAll or just locate, it has to see that same matching image on screen first then you can adjust the confident to your needs. What you're asking is really hard to answer without knowing what you wanted to do, for example if you wanna do that on browser then you can replace it by selenium for example, for normal window can just make a script to let it switch tab for you then let pyautogui detect and do it job

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am actually watching a window on OBS Studio and them, if a predefined event happen, my code "press" alt+tab, execute an action on a different window (of a game), and them alt+tab again to continue monitoring the OBS Studio. I guess that a possible way to not use alt+tab and keep always on the game window would be to make those locate functions "print" the minimized OBS Studio window. Also, i believe it wouldnt be so hard to code a locate function, but again, i guess that i would have to "printscreen" a minimized window so i can scan the png pixels.